# Handling key events not working in service

Tags: android, android-event

I am Facing a problem and problem is I started service in activity, I used the below method in service class but its not working.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyevent, keyEvent event) {
    if ((keyevent == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {

        return true;
    }
    return onKeyDown(keyevent,event);

}
```

Shall I override keyevents in service class?

Answer (score 0):

> Shall I override keyevents in service class?

No, because there is no `onKeyDown()` method in [the `Service` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can i override volumeup key event in service class??

Comment: @Ramakrishna: AFAIK, that is not possible.

Comment: I am trying to open flash light in keyevent_volume up which is called in service. Is there any other possiblities to open flash light app running in background.

Comment: @Ramakrishna: Bear in mind that not all Android devices have volume keys. There are some keys (and volume *might* be one of them) that trigger broadcasts -- take a look at the various broadcast actions defined on `Intent`.